# Display a RichTextArea as Plain text

Tags: richtextarea

I have a RichTextArea (myRichText__c) in the OLI object.
I was asked to create a VFpage that lists OLIs with x,y,z filters with myRichText__c to be editable.
All work well - see output, though the field shows all the rich text options. Is it possible to convert to plain text just for this VFpage so the description below doesn't show all the rich text options?

[image: Output]

My VF page:

```
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MyOli}" var="oliobj">
                        <apex:column headerValue= "Opp Name">
                        <apex:OutputText value="Opp Name1 "/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Description">
                         <apex:inputfield value="{!oliobj.Long_Line_Item_Description__c}"/>
                         </apex:column>                                                
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

My query in the controller:

```
    string selectquery = 'SELECT opportunity.name,opportunity.stagename,Name,myRichText__c FROM OpportunityLineItem ';
string staticWhere = 'where Start_date__c >= Today';
string searchquery = selectquery+staticWhere;
    MyOli= Database.query(searchquery);
```

Comment: How would you expect the content to be stored in the field if you displayed and captured it as plain text? Salesforce uses an implementation of TinyMCE which is open source, you could check the TinyMCE documentation to see if you can hide the editor through CSS/JS

Comment: Why not create a lightning web component? Just asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution, since you're using a record-level VF page for this editing (rather than some form of list view), is to add a second field that is just a long text area (for example) and to add some automation (apex trigger logic) that copies the rich text's stripped content to the string field, or copies the string field's text into the rich text, depending on which one was set or changed. You'd then use the string field in your VF page.

An alternative is to use an [`apex:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_input.htm) with an appropriate `type` and other attributes, and to add handling in your VF controller that:

- populates the String property the input is bound to using the underlying field's value but applying [`String.stripHtmlTags`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_stripHtmlTags) to ensure the users don't see the HTML markup.
- ensures that saving first copies the String property from the input into the underlying field.
- Applies FLS checks before showing the input. The `apex:inputField` does this automatically, but also controls all the editing functionality. Using `apex:input` gives you more flexibility over the editing functionality, but does no FLS checks (since it isn't directly linked to a field).